# Do I need concurrent installations of Java Runtime Environment 32 and 64?

Tags: java

Can I uninstall Java Runtime Environment 32 without any issues?  I have Java 7 update 51 and Java 7 update 51 (64-bit) both installed.  I want to uninstall the 32-bit version.  I am developing in Java, using the 64-bit JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [java.com](http://java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml), you only need the 64bit JRE if you plan on running a 64bit browser. Windows x64 systems by default have seperate 32 and 64bit versions of IE, so if you plan to use the x64 option (x86 is default), you need a 64bit plugin and JRE.

If you plan to run Firefox/chrome/whatever-other-x86-browser, just use the 32bit.

if you are getting a JDK for development determine what version is appropriate for your IDE or other development tools, and use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing pure Java applications (that is, no C/C++ code linked in) you can eliminate the 32-bit version. The two JRE (Java runtime environment) will work equally as well.

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit JRE is required to use the Java plugin in 32-bit browsers like Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox (on Windows). For developing, just the 64-bit JDK is enough.